# How to handle more than 2 cases in ng-class using ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This is my current code:

```
<div class="vision" ng-class="data.quote > 0 ? 'blue-rapid' : 'gray-rapid'"></div>
```

Ok, this is pretty much clear, but now I have scenario where data.quote can be `0`.

I have tried this:

```
<div class="vision" ng-class="data.quote > 0 ? 'blue-rapid' :
 (data.quote == 0 ? 'black_rapid' : 'gray-rapid')"></div>
```

but it didn't help.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing a quote at the end of `'blue-rapid'`.

Comment: Fixed, but that didn't solve the issue...

Comment: @quirimmo, `ng-class` can either take a string or an object.

Comment: @jcaron , why the above is not working, please? :)

Comment: You're missing the ending quote after `blue-rapid`, twice.

Comment: @jcaron, that is because I wrote code here, didn't C/P it. Fixed, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this. `ng-class` also allows you to use a method, which you should be using. That is way too much logic for a directive.

Your view can be something like:

```
<div class="vision" ng-class="getQuoteClass(data)"></div>
```

Your JS can be something like (whatever suits your intention):

```
// Could also be controllerName.prototype.getQuoteClass()...
$scope.getQuoteClass(data) {
  if (data.quote > 0) {
    return 'blue-rapid';
  }
  return data.quote === 0 ? 'black_rapid' : 'gray-rapid';
}
```

Comment: I'd just add that the nested `else` is unnecessary since you are returning a value...the code could be simplified - `if (data.quote > 0) return 'blue-rapid'; return data.quote === 0 ? 'black_rapid' : 'gray-rapid';